# Keep the status of a ProgressBar

Tags: javascript, php

im new on Javascript and PHP, im coding some timers on cards, but this timers need go displayed with his own progressbar

this is what i just got

```
<progress class="timer1" value="0" max="100">
            </progress> 
            <script src="jQuery.js">
            </script> 
            <script>
            var ar;
             $(document).ready(function(){
               var _sI=[];
               $.ii=function(){
                 ar=arguments;
                 if(ar.length==3){
                   if(_sI[ar[0]]==undefined){
                     _sI[ar[0]]={};
                     }else{
                       clearInterval(_sI[ar[0]].reg);
                       } _sI[ar[0]].fn=ar[2];
                       _sI[ar[0]].t=ar[1];
                       _sI[ar[0]].reg=setInterval(ar[2],ar[1]);
                       }else if(ar.length==1){
                         clearInterval(_sI[ar[0]].reg);
                         }}});
            </script> 
            <script>
            $( document ).ready(function(){
              $.ii('t1',36000,function(){
                t1v=$('.timer1').val();
                if(t1v<100){$('.timer1').val(t1v+1);
                }else{$.ii('t1');
                } });
                 });
            </script>
```

this works GOOD,the bar got increase his size each 36 seconds, my issue here is

i need to do refreshes to the page, at this moment the bar got reset, theres any way to keep the status of the bar through the refreshes?

im coding this on a apache2 server linked to a Mysql (MariaDB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes save it in the `localStorage`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var value = localStorage.getItem("timer1_value") || 0;
    $('.timer1').val(value);
    $.ii('t1', 36000, function () {
        var t1v = $('.timer1').val();
        if (t1v < 100) {
            $('.timer1').val(t1v + 1);
            localStorage.setItem("timer1_value", t1v + 1)
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem("timer1_value");
            $.ii('t1');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLProgressElement': The provided double value is non-finite.

Do you know what i can do?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: i opened the same page on 2 diferents screens and that break this, i suppose was my fault, how i can reset the localStorage?

Comment: Hehehe sorry.  You can use `localStorage.removeItem("name")` or using the Developer Tools > Application > Storage. It's not your fault maybe the code can be improved.

Comment: actually is cool, this solve my issue, thnx bro <3